# Browserify talking to another script

Tags: browserify

I want to use browserify, but I don't want to force users of library to do so. In other words, I want the generated bundle.js to define stuff that other scripts on the same page can find. I tried and failed with:

`browserify -o bundle.js src/if.js`

where:

```
::::::::::::::
index.html
::::::::::::::
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
function go() {
  document.getElementById("victim").innerHTML=C();
}
</script>
<body onLoad="go();">
<div id='victim'>Foo</div>
</body>

::::::::::::::
src/if.js
::::::::::::::
var C = require("./c");

::::::::::::::
src/c.js
::::::::::::::
var A = require("./a");
var B = require("./b");
module.exports = function () { return A() + B(); };

::::::::::::::
src/a.js
::::::::::::::
module.exports = function () { return 10; };

::::::::::::::
src/b.js
::::::::::::::
module.exports = function () { return 20; };
```

This fails with "Reference error: C is not defined."

I don't mind forcing the author of the HTML and his scripts to type something strange, but I don't feel entitled to force him to include browseriy in his build process.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bingo! if.js should read

```
global.C = require("./c");
```